# Geolocation listener[listenerFunc] is undefined

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have searched and found related posts, but none that specifically explain why I'm getting an error from code that is (with slight change) extracted from Mozilla Dev website... Can someone enlighten me?

*I'm using Firefox 47.0.1 on a Windows 7 laptop*

The Geolocation getCurrentPosition() sample code from Mozilla is below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

```
function GeoLocationSuccess(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log(crd);

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
  return true;
}

function GeoLocationError(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
  return true;
}

function GetLocation()
{
    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GeoLocationSuccess, GeoLocationError, options);
    return true;
}
GetLocation();
```

When I execute it, I get the following in my console (I edited/changed lat/long to 99)

```
this.listener[listenerFunc] is undefined NetworkGeolocationProvider.js:544:0 
POST XHR https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 97ms]
Coordinates { latitude: 99.3951796, longitude: 99.374427299999999, altitude: 0, accuracy: 94, altitudeAccuracy: 0, heading: NaN, speed: NaN } 
Your current position is: 
Latitude : 99.3951796 
Longitude: 99.374427299999999 
More or less 94 meters.
```

Why am I getting the error
**this.listener[listenerFunc] is undefined**
?

I have half an idea that as the get is asynchronous it expects to run a function after it has a response however its not clear to me where that function call/name is being requested/named.

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was seeking results prior to DeviceReady... When I delayed my request after DeviceReady, the error went away.

But...

What I am less clear over though is why the error would repeat itself over and over every few seconds when my request was only made once. I put console.log calls into my GeoLocationSuccess() call, and it confirmed I was only calling GeoLocationSuccess() once but despite this the error message repeating several times. I suspect this might be a bug within Firefox 47.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in Firefox 50.0.2

The problem was an error in callback function.

Firefox shows irrelevant error message in this situation